# TypeError: Cannot read property 'resources' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, typeerror, mongoose-schema

I want to create a Mongoose Scheme that's a few layers deep but getting an error :

Here is the code:

```
//Mongoose Model
const MissionSchema = new Schema({

name: {
    type: String,
  },
  objective: [
    {
      resources: [
        {
          x: { type: Number },
          y: { type: Number }
        }
      ]
    }
  ] 
});
```

---

```
// @POST api/mission
// @desc Create A Mission

router.post('/', (req, res) => {

const newMission = new MissionModel({
    name: req.body.name,
    x: req.body.objective.resources.x
  });

  newMission.save().then(mission => res.json(mission));
});
```

I keep getting an error message in my console when testing with Postman

> **TypeError**: Cannot read property `resources` of `undefined`?

- mission name

  - mission objective

    - mission resources

      - mission resources #

Answer (score 0):

**Whenever** you get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property `*propertyName*` of `undefined`

It means that you are calling it on **wrong object or** trying to **read something that doesn't exist**.

In your case it means that in this part of code:

```
x: req.body.objective.resources.x
```

Your `req.body.objective` is `undefined`. You are either referencing the wrong object or it simply returns `undefined`.

---

**Solution:** There are a few things you can do. But first, you should use `console.log(req.body.objective)` on that line and see what it logs.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting:

> **TypeError**: Cannot read property `resources` of `undefined`

because, in your **`request body`**, **`objective`** is not available or **`objective`** property is **`undefined`**

So you need to maintain the flow of execution by using some logic, here I am using the **[ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)**:

So your code will be:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {

const newMission = new MissionModel({

    name: req.body.name,
       x: req.body.objective?(req.body.objective.resources?req.body.objective.resources:'Missing Data is resource'):'Missing data is objective';
  });

  newMission.save().then(mission => res.json(mission));
});
```

Comment: Why not just a use a regular `if...else` statement. This line is quite confusion!

Comment: @ Ivan, You can use what you want. It is in single line but if..else will be multiline.